# Why NSIS return this error "Invalid command: SetRegView"

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to use this command `SetRegView 64` on NSIS script but the compiler says it is a invalid command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the exact compiler error message in your question would help...

SetRegView was added in v2.26 so you are really out of date if you don't have a version that supports it. It can only be used in a `Function` or `Section` but it should warn you if you use it somewhere else.

```
Section
SetRegView 64
WriteRegStr HKCU Software\... ...
SectionEnd
```

Comment: That's it! My NSIS compiler is v2.1. Thank you!